# Copy & Rename & Erase in Java

Tags: java, file

I have two files containing data :

```
- temp.txt
- data.txt
```

I want to replace everything inside `data.txt` by what's in `temp.txt`.
What would be the best way to do it?

Either delete `data.txt` then copy & rename `temp.txt`?
Or delete the content of `data.txt` & write inside it the content of `temp.txt`?

Comment: use buffer reader to read from temp. use a loop that is not end of file. just write to a new file called data.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the easy way to do it is do delete data.txt and create a copy of temp.txt

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you still want temp.txt to exist (from its name, it seems that you no longer want it). If that is the case, use

```
File f = new File("temp.txt");
f.renameTo(data.txt");
```

(make sure to include safety checks).

Or use a system command to do it (on *nix platforms, issue a system command "mv temp.txt data.txt").